# Migrating from Google Global HTTP Batch to API specific Batch endpoint, requests aren't executed but no errors thrown

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

I'm running into trouble migrating from the Google Global HTTP Batch to the API specific Batch endpoint for the Google Directory API (in my case to manage google mail groups).

The instructions provided by Google in their blog post are short and simple:

> PHP 
>   Minimum Google Client Library Version supported is 0.86. Consumer
>   Steps Update to version 0.86 or higher For global batch, confirm that
>   your code does not explicitly specify the global batch path (i.e.
>   "/batch" at the end of the path). If it does, change it to refer to
>   the api/version specific path (example "/batch/library/v1").

I use the Google Client API package for PHP, latest version.
To make a batch of requests one uses the Google_Http_Batch class.
The constructor takes your api client instance and three optional parameters, the last one beeing the batchPath. Defaults to 'batch'.

Seems simple enough, I changed my code and call the constructor with the batch path for the Google Directory API v1:

```
//create a batch
$batch = new Google_Http_Batch($this->google_client, false, null, 'batch/directory/v1');
```

The batch request doesn't throw any errors but the requests that are put in the batch aren't executed.
If I change the batchpath back to `'batch'` the requests are executed.
If I change the batchpath to some arbitrary path I get a 400 Not found error from Google.

So it would appear that the new path *is* correct, however the requests aren't executed for some reason.

Anyone run into the same trouble or any idea what I'm doing wrong? (before I start reporting bugs at google)

Cheers!

Comment: You mention google mail groups and the google directory api.  The change removes the global endpoint, requiring you to direct batch requests to specific api endpoints.  One wonders if you are doing a mismatch by connecting to one API and issuing requests for the other. eg: connecting to directory api, then issuing gmail api requests. Something like that?

Comment: Doesn't appear so. The directory API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/) is used to manage google (mail) groups..

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem and i solved.

You need at least this api version:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases/tag/v2.1.3

and you have to use this batch path 'batch/admin/directory_v1' instead of 'batch/directory/v1'

---

In previous versions the batch path is hardcoded in Google_Http_Batch class:

```
  const BATCH_PATH = 'batch';
```

so if you want change this value, you have to change the constant in this class